# Eslint Vue 3 Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vuejs3

After adding Eslint to my project I get this error in my .vue file in the template part

```
Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint
```

within this code block

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center h-40">
    <div class="bg-blue-500 w-40 h-full"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Basically, adding an attribute to any HTML tag throws this error
I'm using a Vue 3 with the "vue-ts" Vite template.
VSCode is my editor and i'm obviously the ESlint plugin :)
Here is my .eslintrc configuration

```js
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'node': true,
  },
  'extends': [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/base',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
  ],
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 12,
    'parser': '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    'sourceType': 'module'
  },
  'plugins': [
    'vue',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  'rules': {
    'indent': [
      'error',
      'tab'
    ],
    'linebreak-style': [
      'error',
      'unix'
    ],
    'quotes': [
      'error',
      'single'
    ],
    'semi': [
      'error',
      'never'
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have not set the `parser` option in your eslint configuration.  From the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/plugins#specifying-parser):

> By default, ESLint uses [Espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) as its parser. […] To indicate the npm module to use as your parser, specify it using the `parser` option in your `.eslintrc` file.

Use [vue-eslint-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-eslint-parser) to lint the `<template>` of `.vue` files:

```
{
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser"
}
```

As noted by @ipid and @jfbloom22 you may also need to set `parserOptions.parser`. This is documented [here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser).

```
{
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": { 
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser" 
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks! Note that one may need to set `"parserOptions": { "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser" }` after the `"parser"` setting.

Comment: To add to the fix from [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598327/3873308), this package is a child dependency of `eslint-plugin-vue` if you're already using it. Verify with `npm ls vue-eslint-parser`.

Comment: @ipid's answer was key for me.  There is something about having both parser settings.  

`parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
    parserOptions: {
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',`

Comment: I found where having both parsers configured is actually documented!  https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser

Answer (score 2):

you can handle it like this

```
parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
```

or

```
extends: [
    'plugin:vue/base',
],
```

Final result

```
parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
extends: [
     'plugin:vue/base',
     'eslint:recommended',
     'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
     'plugin:vue/essential',
     'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
     'plugin:prettier/recommended',
     'eslint-config-prettier'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

parser solution is okay, but maybe for someone case like me. issue it was `eslint` cashing so I removed the file and added it again.